# Неправильно работает относительный путь к файлу при добавлении картинки в HTML

Tags: java, html, spring

Хочу поставить картинку на странице сайта. Картинка лежит в той же папке, где и HTML-шаблон, в котором нужно картинку отобразить.

**Как я добавляю картинку**

`<img src="logo.png">`

**Сервер написан на Java, Фреймворк Spring.**

**Проблема**

При загрузке сайта выходит не нужная картинка, а значок ошибки картинки.При нажатии на этот значок правой кнопкой мыши, и выбора пункта "открыть картинку в новой вкладке", открывается новая вкладка, и путь к картинке указан не тот, что мне нужен, а к домену моего сайта через слэш добавляется название картинки.

**Вопрос**

Как сделать так, чтобы картинка не искалась по ссылке к моему сайту, а искалась как файл, который находится внутри папки с кодом сайта?

Comment: "HTML-шаблон" - это что значит? Какой адрес в браузере, когда в нем открыта страница?

Comment: HTML шаблон - это файл с HTML, который показывается при переходе по ссылке. Когда открыта страница в браузере, адрес localhost:8080, а когда нажимаю открыть картинку в новой вкладке localhost:8080/logo.png

Comment: какой сервер используется?

Comment: @Grundy Используется сервер на Java с фреймворком Spring.

Comment: в spring настраивается доступ к статическим ресурсам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать директорию "static" внутри директории "resources", положить в директорию "static" нужную картинку.

Далее, вместо `<img src="logo.png">` использовать `<img src="/logo.png" alt="">`

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле тот путь, который указан в `src` мало связан с путем на диске. Если Вы используете Spring, то, там реализована модель MVC, т.е. для каждого запроса существует контроллер, который его обрабатывает.

Когда Вы, например, обращаетесь к URL страницы, спринг использует специальный механизм, называемый реквест маппингом, который определяет, какой контроллер будет обрабатывать запрос.

То же и с ресурсами. Ваш `<img src="logo.png">` означает, что браузер отправит запрос на вебсервер в котором путь отсчитывается от корня базового урла (в Вашем случае - домена). Механизм маппинга попробует найти подходящий контроллер, для такого запроса.

Подводя итог, Вам надо [сконфигурировать такой маппинг](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates), который направит запрос на контроллер, отвечающий за выдачу картинок. Этот контроллер уже прочитает файл из того места, откуда Вы ему скажете, и вернет его браузеру. Из той же папки где лежит шаблон или из любой другой.